# Remove folder after commit in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I just commit a folder to my svn repository accidentally. Now when i tried to do `svn update`. Its giving me this issue:

```
svn: Failed to add directory 'public/data': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
```

So how can i resolve this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the repository browser, then delete the accidentally committed folder from there.

Then you can run the update without getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is renaming the folder that you commited accidentally, then make what you want and then merge content if is necessary, finally delete this wrong folder.

Hope it helps.